# Visual Studio 2019 loads the wrong assembly

Tags: visual-studio, dll

I have a C# project that references an external library DLL. Initially I had added the reference with the location of this library pointing to a folder:

```
C:\Program Files\Siemens\Automation\Portal V15\PublicAPI\V15\Siemens.Engineering.dll
```

I need to update this assembly to a new version, so I removed the reference and re-added it with the new path (Portal V17 instead of V15):

```
C:\Program Files\Siemens\Automation\Portal V17\PublicAPI\V15\Siemens.Engineering.dll
```

However, no matter what I do, Visual Studio keeps loading the old assembly. I can see this in the output of the debugger and functionally I know the wrong file is being loaded:

```
'TIA Portal Vacuum Updater.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: TIA Portal Vacuum Updater.exe): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Siemens\Automation\Portal V15\PublicAPI\V15\Siemens.Engineering.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
```

I have "Copy Local" set to true on the reference properties, and the right assembly is copied to the output folder, but nonetheless the wrong version still gets loaded. I have read somewhere that adding the following to my .csproj could fix the issue, but it doesn't do it for me :

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <AssemblySearchPaths>{HintPathFromItem};{TargetFrameworkDirectory};{RawFileName}</AssemblySearchPaths>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Any tips would be appreciated!

Thanks,
Rodrigo

Comment: Isn't that `Siemens.Engineering` assembly available as a NuGet package?

Comment: Nope, it's a very specific library that implements an API for Siemen PLCs engineering stations (TIA Portal). It is shipped with the software.